# Middle align label & textbox using div

Tags: html, asp.net, css

there..
i have asp.net webform app that has sever labels and textboxes aligned side by side.

If you'll have a look below.

[image: desiner]

i want the label text say for example complaint date to be aligned exactly to the middle of the textbox.
like this.

[image: a]

Some more details:
i have a one div left that holds lable's and right div that holds textbox.
like so

```
<div class="left" style="height:50px;" runat="server" >
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="#0066ff" Text="Complaint Date"></asp:Label>
    </div>
<div class="right">
        &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="Date" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
   </div>
```

and my css to align them together is something like this..

```
.left {
height:25px;
width: 152px;
float: left;
text-align: right;
vertical-align:middle;
}

.right {

width: 43%;
margin-left: 10px;
float:right;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

what other formatting do i have to do to make the label and text box be middle alinged?
thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore) and [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aafter) pseudo elements to achieve this. Apply `display:block` and set it's `height` to

`((total height of the container div - height of contents)/2)`

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/8nNuH/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to give your labels and textboxes a fixed width and `margin:0 auto;` to horizontally align them.
Try this:

```
.left label {
    width:50px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.right input[type="text"] {
    width:50px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.left label {
    width:50px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.right input[type="text"] {
    width:50px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 30px;
}
```